# YouTube api URL to get Shares count

Tags: video, youtube, count, share

Can anyone please give me the exact YouTube api URL Example from which i can find the Share Count of a Video. For Example: The following URL works to find the comments of a Youtube Video.

[https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/5JetouM8_z8/comments](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/5JetouM8%5fz8/comments)

In the same way can anyone please give a proper url example for shares count of a video.

Thank You in advance.

Regards,
Ritesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been very long since I posted this question. But my answer might be of some help to others. 
The YouTube API V2 is getting deprecated and hence I migrated from v2 to v3. But the metric 'share count' is only available for YouTube Analytics. It is a core metric and one can find the shares of his own channels and videos only using YouTube Analytics.
For more details visit the page:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets#shares

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Youtube Analytics to get metrics data for YOUR OWN videos, channels, etc.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets